# How to build my own Grid Layout in ANDROID so that it can work with the devices which are below API 14

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, grid, grid-layout

I want to build a Calculator App, in which I want to format all the required buttons in such a way that, they all appears in a Grid form to me....
The one which I've made is only running on Android 4.0 & above devices...But I want that my calculator app should run on maximum Android devices(Android 2.2 & above) & which have a GridLayout in it..!

Please help me by suggesting me some code or anything else...
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

A backwards compatible implementation (for API level 7 and up) of `GridLayout` is also available as Android library project in the support library. After you've downloaded this add-on, you'll find an Android library project in your local sdk folder located at:

```
<sdk_folder>\extras\android\compatibility\v7\gridlayout
```

Set it up as dependency of the project you're working on. After that, you'll need to change the references throughout your project from the level 14 version to this compatibility one in order to support pre-ICS devices. Usage should be similar, if not identical.

See also:

- [GridLayout in Android 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126625/gridlayout-in-android-2-0/11126742#11126742)
- [Grid Layout support in android API 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278358/grid-layout-support-in-android-api-10/10278642#10278642)

Comment: I didn't found the gridlayout, in my sdk_folder..Please help what to do now!!

Comment: @user1563528: Did you make sure you downloaded the support library and/or that it's up to date? Look for 'Android Support' under Extras in the SDK Manager.