# GridLayout v7 failed to instantiate (with Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, grid-layout

I got the following message:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)

So I looked for a solution and I found that:

1. [Setting up Android support package v7 for eclipse - GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133078/setting-up-android-support-package-v7-for-eclipse-gridlayout) Not working
2. [Gridview v7 support for older api android.support.v7.widget.Gridlayout failed to instaniate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822977/gridview-v7-support-for-older-api-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to) Not working
3. [Eclipse giving an error of android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773981/eclipse-giving-an-error-of-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to-instan) Not working

Yes, none of these solutions worked for me...

Here is the layout.xml which is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Minimum API is 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added its support-v7-gridlayout library in your project?

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? Can you show the screenshot of your layout with error?

Comment: Here is two screenshorts
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/135233screen1.png
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/509245screen2.png

Comment: Well, I just found the issue. I had to update the android-support-v4.jar... Sorry, but sometime, I'm so dumb. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out as below:

`File->Import->Existing Android code into workspace` Specify `android-sdk-[platform]/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout` and add the project library of `GridLayout` in your workspace.

After importing library into your workspace you need to import the `GridLayout` library project as an Android library project in your project to make it work.

EDIT: For all who have this issue, try to update the android-support-v4.jar.